# Complex SQL query to get serialnumber data from shopware

Tags: mysql, sql, multiple-tables, shopware

Good morning everyone,
a few days ago I installed a shopware 5 instance on my server to mess around with. 
Shopware has a feature to sell ESD products and assign a unique serialnumber to each purchase which I now need to verify from an external program.
Sadly shopware splits everything in multiple tables which makes it pretty hard to understand.

What I have:
 - A users email address
 - A users licence

What I want:
The name of the product that is licenced to the email address with the given licence.
The article serial gets stored in "a_articles_esd_serials" as "serialnumber". The article name gets stored in "s_articles" as "name".

What I already tried:
I tried to create a SQL query to get the serialnumbers matching a product. Just to create myself a base. But this already fails with "s_articles.id is not defined" which is impossible since its definetly there and of course gets set in autocomplete in phpmyadmin.

```
SELECT arts.name
FROM s_articles arts
JOIN s_articles_esd arts_esd ON arts_esd.articleID = s_articles.id
JOIN s_order_esd order_esd ON order_esd.esdID = arts_esd.id
JOIN s_articles_esd_serials serials ON serials.esdID = order_esd.esdID
```

Informations about the tables:
I've made this designer view for you to understand what the tables look like.

[Designer view of the given tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEAra.png)

As said, shopware splits up a few things.

Input:

```
{
"mail": "example@example.com",
"licence": "ABCDEFGH"
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{[
"mail": "example@example.com",
"licence": "ABCDEFGH",
"product": "Awesome product name" //THIS WOULD BE NULL IF NOTHING FOUND
]}
```

Can someone probably help me to achieve this?
Would be pretty nice since I'm somehow blocked in my head rn.

Greets!

Comment: You assigned a correlation name to your table: `FROM s_articles arts`, so you must use that name when referencing its columns.

Comment: @mustaccio How could I.. nevermind thanks!
I was able to adjust my query with your comment.

But now I'm facing a different problem.
Do you mind answering to this question so that I can answer directly, not using comments (character limit)?

Comment: you can always edit your question to add/remove information, and/or answer it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I was able to help myself using multiple sub querys.

```
SELECT arts.name FROM s_articles arts WHERE arts.id = (SELECT arts_esd.articleID FROM s_articles_esd arts_esd WHERE arts_esd.id = (SELECT oesd.esdID FROM s_order_esd oesd WHERE oesd.serialID = (SELECT serials.id FROM s_articles_esd_serials serials WHERE serials.serialnumber = "ABCDEFGH") AND oesd.userID = (SELECT usr.id FROM s_user usr WHERE email = 'example@example.com')))
```